# Set a sound frequency with Java code

Tags: java, audio, frequency, piano

Is there any methods to set a sound files frequency? I am trying to create a piano and this works as it should work. However, I miss one note that is D#, but I can not find any D# sound from internet that would match the ones I am currently using. So is there any possibility to use one sound file, and then tone it's frequency up with code?

It would be also cool if this worked, I could make octave buttons and play piano from any octave and not just from the original (that's used in the sound files).

Comment: if you have a sound file with a lower pitch, try interpolating it

Comment: I do have, I am also unsure that how much should I interpolate it to match D#. But I'd really love if there was a code or API to change the pitch by code